# Forking the chain locally

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, forks, blockchain-fork, project-fork

I would like to fork the ETH chain and play around with it locally, maybe even buy a few raspberry pi's and run some nodes just to present it visually.

Can someone please point me to some documentation or videos regarding this or explain how this would be done?

Appreciate it <3

Answer (score 0):

There are great CLI tooling in foundry and hardhat on how to do this.

- Susheen did a great write up on [using foundry to fork mainnet
  here](https://mirror.xyz/susheen.eth/bRCzT2QLdNINMVk8251udkfjHW_T9ascCQ1DV9hURz0).
- If you prefer hardhat, [they have a guide in their docs on how to do
  it](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks).

I would guide you to use as foundry as I find it better overall and the dev team are being out some very cool updates but both will work good.